# HttpClient with dynamic proxy

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient, http-proxy

I have a method `MultiLikeAsync(username, password, proxy)` which can be executed multiple times and each time with different username, password, proxy or no proxy at all.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
{
    Class class = new Class();
    await class.MultiLikeAsync(random_username, random_password, random_proxy);
}
```

This is my current setup:

```cs
public class Class
{
    private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    static Class()
    {
        if (_httpClient == null)
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

            if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
            {
                handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            }

            _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        }
    }
    
    public async Task MultiLikeAsync(string username, string password, string proxy = null)
    {
        //_httpClient.Proxy = ??? // Can't do that
        
        // first request
        HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "url");
    
        // Polly
        var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(1);
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await timeoutPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async ct => await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest, ct), CancellationToken.None);
        
        // second request
        HttpRequestMessage httpRequest2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "different_url");

        // Polly
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse2 = await timeoutPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async ct => await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest2, ct), CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

The problem with my solution is that I can't dynamically set `_httpClient.Proxy` for each `MultiLikeAsync` call. It has to be set along with `HttpClientHandler` during `HttpClient` instantiation or with multiple `HttpClient` instances.

It's a bad idea to reinstantiate `HttpClient` more than once, because it creates socket exhaustion and that's the reason they introduced `IHttpClientFactory` in .NET Core 2.1. Even if I used `IHttpClientFactory`, I would have had same problem, because it doesn't allow me to dynamically change proxies for each request. More info [about it](https://iqunlock.com/httpclient-csharp-ihttpclientfactory/#conclusion).

I need a solution immune to socket exhaustion (just like `IHttpClientFactory`) that allows me use a different proxy for each `MultiLikeAsync` call. Additionally, I want to keep my [Polly Timeout](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#timeout).

**Edit:**

After your example given below, it's kinda the same. It doesn't close the `TIME_WAIT` requests. They are disposed after 240 seconds.

[image]

```cs
public class Class
{
    private const int Timeout = 6;
    
    public async Task MultiLikeAsync(string username, string password, string proxy = null)
    {
        using HttpClientHandler httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

        if (proxy != null)
        {
            httpHandler.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy, true);
        }

        if (httpHandler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
        {
            httpHandler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        }

        using HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler);
        
        try
        {
            using HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "url");
            
            var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(Timeout);
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await timeoutPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async ct => await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest, ct), CancellationToken.None);
            
            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                
                ...
            }
            
            using HttpRequestMessage httpRequest2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "different_url");
        
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse2 = await timeoutPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async ct => await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest2, ct), CancellationToken.None);
        
            if (httpResponse2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await httpResponse2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                
                ...
            }
        }
        catch (TimeoutRejectedException ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException is TaskCanceledException)
            {
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException is SocketException)
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On the contrary, HttpClientFactory allows you to register named clients with the configurations you want  and retrieve the one you want at runtime

Comment: The one with multiple `services.AddHttpClient("FirstClient", ...); services.AddHttpClient("SecondClient", ...)` in ConfigureServices and `_clientFactory.CreateClient("FirstClient");`? I don't think it suits my case, because I have unknown amount of clients.

Comment: Socket exhaustion is prevented by reusing HttpClient, *not* HttpClientFactory. HttpClientFactory is needed to recycle HttpClient instances to handle DNS registration changes. Do you really need a different proxy for *every* call? This means you need a different *socket* for every call too, so reusing an HttpClient wouldn't help. If you use the same proxy more than once, you should be able to use and reuse different HttpClient (or rather, HttpClientHandler instances) for each proxy

Comment: As for what suits your case - what is that? You can't call a client without finding out about it at some point. When do you find out? How? Do you read the details from some configuration? Or do users just type the settings resulting in one-off calls? If the same proxy is never reused there's no point in reusing HttpClient. Otherwise you could eg store them in a Dictionary or ConcurrentDictionary based on some key and reuse them

Comment: That's correct. Different proxy = different socket, this actually makes sense now, thanks. If you look at those two `HttpRequestMessage` calls in `MultiLikeAsync`, they can be executed with same proxy, but `MultiLikeAsync` itself should be executed with different HttpClients/proxies.

Comment: You can implement an `IWebProxy`, which gets called for every request, that chooses which proxy to use based on a `Uri`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm confused. What should I do now? Use `IHttpClientFactory` or multiple `HttpClient` instances? IHttpClientFactory just because it handles the DNS?

Comment: I answered once at Russian SO to the similar question. Look at the [code example](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115814/373567), afaik it works but with `HttpClient` per proxy. You may run out of sockets if you create `HttpClient` per request, but it can be ok to have `HttpClient` per proxy and reuse it. `IHttpClientFactory` can also help to improve it.

Comment: Thanks, after your comments I edited my question with what I did. How can I know if it handles the DNS registration changes?

Comment: @nop   you don't have to use IHttpClientFactory to handle DNS recycling.  You can use SocketsHttpHandler to control the connection pooling. Example here: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-connection-pooling-in-dotnet-core

Comment: @MikeJ, is it just me or it's doable only with one HttpClient instance, which means I cannot set more than one proxy?

Comment: What the heck, if I don't dispose `HttpClient`, it doesn't leave TIME_WAIT tracks in `netstat`?

Comment: @nop yeah, sorry.  looking at the source the proxy is kept at the connection pool level.  So while you can handle DNS issues without the factory the proxy is another matter.  IHttpClientFactory may be answer although I'm not sure it's a perfect fit either.  Note I don't think some of the above comments are accurate - HttpClient does not hold a socket, it's the HttpMessageHandler subclass that actually manages the connection and the purpose of the IHttpClientFactory is to manage those handler instances.